# K.eval() giving out of memory error in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, out-of-memory, tensor

I am using `keras.backend.eval()` to convert the output tensor of hypercolumns model generated from a image classification network to numpy array and it is running fine for a few tensors (like 120 tensors). I am using a generator to load the image one by one to the input of model but still after running for 120 tensors, it is giving me `out of memory` error. What could be the potential problem behind this and are there any other ways to convert a tensor to numpy array.

here is the code:

```
def gethypercols(model,image):
    model = hypercol_model(model)
    output = model.predict(image)
    factor = 2
    for i in range(len(output)):
            output[i] = tf.convert_to_tensor(output[i],np.float32)
            output[i] = (ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))(output[i])
            output[i] = (Conv2D(100,(3,3)))(output[i])
            if i in (0,1,2):
                    output[i] = UpSampling2D(size = (factor**2,factor**2),interpolation='bilinear')(output[i])
            elif i in (3,4,5,6):
                    output[i] = UpSampling2D(size = (factor**3,factor**3),interpolation='bilinear')(output[i])
            elif i in (7,8,9,10,11,12):
                    output[i] = UpSampling2D(size = (factor**4,factor**4),interpolation='bilinear')(output[i])
            else:
                    output[i] = UpSampling2D(size = (factor**5,factor**5),interpolation='bilinear')(output[i])
    out = Add()([output[0],output[1],output[2],output[3],output[4],output[5],output[6],output[7],output[8],output[9],output[10],output[11],output[12],output[13],output[14],output[15]])
    out = (Activation('sigmoid'))(out)
    print(out.shape)
    out = (ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))(out)
    out = (Conv2D(20,(3,3)))(out)
    print('conversion of tensor to numpy')
    outarray = tf.squeeze(out)
    outarray = K.eval(outarray)
    ourarray = np.array(outarray)
    return outarray

def hypercol_model(model):
        hypercol_model = Model(inputs=[model.input],outputs=[model.get_layer('add_1').output,model.get_layer('add_2').output,model.get_layer('add_3').output,model.get_layer('add_4').output,model.get_layer('add_5').output,model.get_layer('add_6').output,model.get_layer('add_7').output,model.get_layer('add_8').output,model.get_layer('add_9').output,model.get_layer('add_10').output,model.get_layer('add_11').output,model.get_layer('add_12').output,model.get_layer('add_13').output,model.get_layer('add_14').output,model.get_layer('add_15').output,model.get_layer('add_16').output])
        return hypercol_model
```

The model here is the image classification model loaded like this:

```
model = load_model('ResnetTL4.h5',custom_objects={'precision_m': precision_m,'recall_m':recall_m})
```

And the image is being loaded by a generator given below:

```
def initgenerator(batch_size,target_size,train_images_list):
        mean_pixel = np.array([104.0, 117.0, 123.0])
        train_images_list = iter(train_images_list)
        target_size = target_size[:2]
        while True:
            img_out = np.zeros(((batch_size,)+target_size+(3,)))
            for i in range(batch_size):
                img_file = next(train_images_list)
                print(img_file)                                                                                                                                                             img_path = 'JPEGImages/'+img_file+'.jpg'                                                                                                                                    print(img_path)                                                                                                                                                             # Read and resize image and mask
                img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) # BGR                                                                                                                          img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) #RGB                                                                                                                             print(img.shape)                                                                                                                                                            img = nd.zoom(img.astype('float32'),(224/float(img.shape[0]),224/float(img.shape[1]), 1.0),order=1)                                                                        
                img = img - mean_pixel                                                                                                                                                      
                img_out[i,:,:,:] = img.astype(np.float32)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            yield(img_out)
```

EDIT2:

```
    def gethypercols(model,image):
        model = hypercol_model(model)
        output = model.predict(image)                                                                                                                                               
        print(len(output))
        gen = gen_model(model)
        outarray = gen.predict(image)
        print(outarray.shape)
        print(type(outarray))
        outarray = np.squeeze(outarray)
        return outarray

    def gen_model(model):
            output = model.output
            print(type(output))
            factor = 2
            print(len(output))
            for i in range(len(output)):
                    output[i] = (ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))(output[i])
                    output[i] = (Conv2D(100,(3,3)))(output[i])
                    if i in (0,1,2):
                            output[i] = UpSampling2D(size = (factor**2,factor**2),interpolation='bilinear')(output[i])
                    elif i in (3,4,5,6):
                            output[i] = UpSampling2D(size = (factor**3,factor**3),interpolation='bilinear')(output[i])
                    elif i in (7,8,9,10,11,12):
                            output[i] = UpSampling2D(size = (factor**4,factor**4),interpolation='bilinear')(output[i])
                    else:
                            output[i] = UpSampling2D(size = (factor**5,factor**5),interpolation='bilinear')(output[i])
            out = Add(name='add100')([output[0],output[1],output[2],output[3],output[4],output[5],output[6],output[7],output[8],output[9],output[10],output[11],output[12],output[13],output[14],output[15]])
            out = (Activation('sigmoid',name='act2'))(out)
            out = (ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))(out)
            out = (Conv2D(20,(3,3)))(out)
            model = Model(inputs=[model.input],outputs=[out])
            return model

    def hypercol_model(model):
            hypercol_model = Model(inputs=[model.input],outputs=[model.get_layer('add_1').output,model.get_layer('add_2').output,model.get_layer('add_3').output,model.get_layer('add_4').output,model.get_layer('add_5').output,model.get_layer('add_6').output,model.get_layer('add_7').output,model.get_layer('add_8').output,model.get_layer('add_9').output,model.get_layer('add_10').output,model.get_layer('add_11').output,model.get_layer('add_12').output,model.get_layer('add_13').output,model.get_layer('add_14').output,model.get_layer('add_15').output,model.get_layer('add_16').output])
            return hypercol_model
```

Comment: Please add full code, you could be doing something wrong and actually using the whole memory.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, added the code. I am trying to implement the concept of hypercolumns here.

Comment: Your code is very memory inefficient, what is the need to transform the output model to tensor and feed it to another model? You should define all  the models and call predict on them with the right data.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, you mean conversion of numpy to tensor is not required? I am working a building a weakly supervised model and I want to store this output to a pickle file and when i am trying to store the tensor directly in a pickle using `pickle.dump` , it is giving me `TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects` error. I also want to further access each element of the tensor, is there any better way other than converting it to numpy array?

Comment: You need to input numpy arrays and get numpy array outputs, build a model and use model.predict with it

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro how do we get numpy array outputs, when i use `model.predict` it gives the tensor output isn't it?

Comment: No, its a numpy array

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, I changed the code as in EDIT2 such that it gives numpy array output but still I am getting out of memory error after a few images.